# Daisy chaining EV3 with RobotC

Tags: ev3, programming, robotc

I'm trying to run EV3 programs with RobotC and trying run on EV3 Daisy Chaining. I have three independent EV3 bricks labelled A,B,C.

I want, according to the color reading by the color sensor on port 1 on brick A, the motors connected to bricks B and C have distinct behaviours.